# GetHashCode — вычисление хэш

Tags: c#, хеширование

Мне интересно узнать, каким образом формируется хэш объекта в C#. Например, есть тестовый класс:

```
public class A
{
    public int b = 0;
    public int c;
}
```

Далее где-нибудь в коде:

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
a1.c = 10;
a2.c = 10;
```

a1 и a2, по логике вещей, совершенно идентичны. Но для C# нет. Их хэши различны. 
Конечно же, понятно, что это различие может быть оправдано, например, различием адресами в памяти, ну или временем создания, в конце концов :). Так вот хочется точно узнать, как же формируются хэши объектов и чем обосновывается их различие для идентичных пользовательских объектов.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Для начала, поскольку ваш класс `A` не переопределяет `GetHashCode()`, эта функция наследуется от `object`.

Точный алгоритм вычисления `GetHashCode()` для `object` [не специфицирован](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode):

> Реализация `GetHashCode` по умолчанию не гарантирует уникальные значения для различных объектов. Кроме того, .NET Framework не гарантирует, что реализация `GetHashCode` по умолчанию, в том числе значения, возвращаемые ей, не поменяются при смене версии фреймворка. Соответственно, значение функции `GetHashCode` по умолчанию не должно быть использована как уникальный идентификатор объекта с целью хеширования.

То, что вам два объекта *кажутся* идентичными, не гарантирует, что у них при реализации по умолчанию совпадут хеш-коды. С другой стороны, посудите сами: если у двух людей совпадает имя и фамилия, это ведь ещё не значит, что это один и тот же человек? Так и .NET framework, если у двух экземпляров класса `A` совпадают все поля, ещё не считает эти экземпляры *одним и тем же* объектом. Соответственно, по умолчанию используется что угодно -- например, адрес при создании или время создания, документация не говорит о точном методе. Если вас не устраивает поведение по умолчанию, вы должны его перекрыть.

Если ваш класс не использует операцию `Equals` и не является ключом в хеш-таблицах, в принципе можно ничего и не делать, вас должно устраивать и поведение по умолчанию. Но если ваш класс служит ключом, вам необходимо переопределить как `Equals`, так и `GetHashCode()`, причём согласованным образом: если `x.Equals(y)` возвращает `true`, то и хеш-коды у `x` и `y` **обязаны** совпадать.

Отсюда следует, что вы должны переопределять функцию `GetHashCode()` вместе с функцией `Equals`. Например, так:

```
public class A
{
    public int b = 0;
    public int c;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as A);
    }

    public bool Equals(A that)
    {
        if (that == null)
            return false;
        return this.b == that.b && this.c == that.c;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return b.GetHashCode() * 13 + c.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

В C#, в отличие от многих других языков, есть объекты [двух типов](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/): объекты, полностью определяющиеся своими атрибутами (то есть, полями), и объекты, представляющие собой самостоятельную сущность, не сводящуюся лишь к значениям атрибутов.

Примером объекта первого типа являются, например, числа: если вы пишете

```
x = 5;
y = 5;
```

-- нет никакой разницы между первой и второй пятёркой, это *одна и та же сущность*. Подобные штуки называются в .NET типами-значениями и вводятся ключевым словом `struct`. Для них метод `Equals` по умолчанию сравнивает значения всех полей, и если они равны, заключает, что и структуры равны, одинаковы. Поэтому структуры *можно* копировать по значению, структуру *можно* безболезненно заменить на её копию. (Метод `GetHashCode` по умолчанию определён соответствующим образом: для *равных* структур он гарантированно возвращает одинаковый хеш.)

Примером другой сущности может служить, например, автомобиль, атрибутами которого являются марка, год выпуска, мощность двигателя и т. п. Два автомобиля с одинаковыми техническими параметрами -- это всё же *разные* автомобили. Такие объекты в C# называются *ссылочными типами* и вводятся ключевым словом `class`. Для классов, соответственно, реализация `Equals` по умолчанию не имеет права предполагать, что одинаковые значения полей автоматически означают равенство, каждый экземпляр класса считается *уникальным*.

Подумайте, не нужна ли вам на самом деле вместо класса `A` структура?

Вопрос о том, определяемся ли мы все, люди, лишь нашим набором параметров, или в нас есть что-то вне этого, не так уж прост.

Comment: Спасибо. Это, несомненно, очень интересно :) Но вы вели речь в основном о том, что было мне уже известно, или же о том, что очевидно( я про "два типа" объектов, к примеру ). Вот о том, как работают методы GetHashCode() и Equals() для структур я, честно говоря, даже не задумывался( мне кажется, я это мог бы предположить ). Тем не менее, я все же так и не понял, откуда берется различие в возвращаемых методом GetHashCode() хэшах в пользовательских типах( классах ) с идентичным набором полей...опираясь на что генерируется хэш? Вот, что действительно хочется узнать.

Comment: @Hancock: В документации явно сказано, что алгоритм _не специфицирован_, я же приводил цитату. Это значит, что для `GetHashCode` может быть _любой_ алгоритм вычисления, не обязательно базирующийся на значениях полей. _Текущая_ версия .NET воспользовалась дарованной ей свободой не рассматривать значения полей, следующая версия может их рассматривать, и то и другое правильно. Как именно считает текущая версия, документация не говорит, да нам это и не нужно знать, так как алгоритм может поменяться в любую минуту.

Comment: @Hancock: Если вам нужно, чтобы алгоритм обладал какими-то свойствами (например, учитывал значения полей), вам _необходимо_ переопределить `equals` и `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, понял: никто из разработчиков точно не знает, как работает метод GetHashCode().

Comment: @Hancock вот тебя статейка от одного из разработчиков C# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/archive/2011/03/20/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @Hancock: разработчики-то знают, но вам это знание _не нужно_, и опираться на него (если бы оно было доступно) вредно и даже опасно. Потому что этот алгоритм может поменяться в любую секунду.