# Переопределение GetHashCode(): создание хэш по User.Surname и User.Name

Tags: c#, .net

### КОД

Есть класс c переопределенным методом `Equals()`

```
/// <summary>
/// Описание пользователя
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Объект данного класса также является сущностью базы данных</remarks>
public class User
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is User secondUser))
            return false;

        return this.Surname.Equals(secondUser.Surname) && this.Name.Equals(secondUser.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //?
    }
}
```

---

### ВОПРОС

Не знаю как переопределить метод `GetHashCode()` согласно моему условию уникальности - достаточно, чтобы совпадало фамилия и имя.

---

### МОИ ПОИСКИ

Из всего поиска хочется выделить вот эти две статьи

1. [CA2218: переопределяйте GetHashCode при переопределении Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182358.aspx).
   Хоть я и не новичок в мире программирования, но термин поразрядная операция `^` меня вводит просто в ступор. Не понимаю, что это такое. Думал это больше из мира `Си`.
2. [GetHashCode — вычисление хэш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198504/gethashcode-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88). Эта статься больше ввела меня в курс дела, но тут у автора в качестве полей типы значимые и поэтому полегче.

Хотел сказать, что и эти две статьи не помогли мне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вычисление хэшкода должно быть быстрым (быстрее полного сравнения), и не должно плодить мусор.

Варианты типа `(Name+Surname).GetHashCode()`

1. Создадут временную строку
2. Посчитают по ней хэш
3. Выбросят временную строку в мусор

Причем это произойдет для обоих сравниваемых объектов. Такое вычисление хэшкода - дороже, чем прямое сравнение объектов.

Судя по комментарию

```
/// <remarks>Объект данного класса также является сущностью базы данных</remarks>
```

у вас этот класс будет лежать в базе данных. И у него скорее всего будет поле `UserID`. Вот и реализуйте `GetHashCode` как

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.UserID.GetHashCode(); 
}
```

или даже

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.UserID; 
}
```

И, соответственно, дописать сравнение по `UserID` в `Equals` - пользователи с разным `UserID` не должны считаться Equal;

Если `UserID` нет, то используйте в качестве хэшкода комбинацию хэшкодов неизменяемых полей (только тех, которые используются в `Equals`):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Name.GetHashCode() * 13 + Surname.GetHashCode();
}
```

Ну или просто возвращайте хэш какого-то *достаточно уникального* поля, если нет альтернатив:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Surname.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: UserID можно использовать только если он в Equals тоже используется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, естественно, сейчас допишу

Comment: Т.е. получается теперь я могу в методе `Equals()` просто написать `return this.GetHashCode() == secondUser.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: @adamshakhabov нет!!!

Comment: @PavelMayorov вообще нет или относительно сценария какого-то? К примеру: если я создаю коллекцию `HashSet<T>` и загоняю туда подряд объекты `User`, а он (коллекция `HashSet<T>`) в свою очередь, получая хэш-код добавляемого объекта, не будет допускать дублирования объектов.

Comment: @adamshakhabov если хэшкод разный - объекты разные. если хэшкод одинаковый - объекты могут быть разными, а могут быть одинаковые. тот же HashSet вполне хранит в себе объекты с одинаковым хэшем. При попытке Add он проверяет "есть ли уже объекты с таким хэшем". Если нет - то он добавляет новый объект Если есть - то он проходит по всем объектам с таким же хэшем, и вызывает Equals у каждого.

Comment: @adamshakhabov В качестве простой аналогии - представьте, что хэшкод - это первая буква фамилии. Если у людей разная первая буква фамилии - то это разные люди. Если одинаковая - то для выяснения, разные ли они, вам придется сравнить полное имя. А HashSet - это телефонный справочник, позволяющий быстро узнать, есть ли в городе **С**мит Джон, проверяя только тех, кто перечислен в разделе **С**. В нем вполне может быть много людей на С, но проверять по нему все равно быстрее, чем перебирать всех подряд от А о Я.

Comment: Т.е. можно сказать, что `хеш` - это что-то на подобии `индекса` базы данных?