# Зачем переопределять методы Equals() и GetHashCode() в C#

Tags: c#, equals

Можете объяснить, зачем в коде переопределять данные методы в коде. И при этом почему то пишут что они должны переопределяться вместе.
Вот даже просто взял пример... зачем тут это, почему без этого переопределения не работает???? Как оно все устроено????

```
Person[] students = { new Person("Tom"), new Person("Bob"), new Person("Sam") };
Person[] employees = { new Person("Tom"), new Person("Bob"), new Person("Mike") };

// объединение последовательностей
var people = students.Union(employees);

foreach (Person person in people)
  Console.WriteLine(person.Name);


class Person
{
  public string Name { get;}
  public Person(string name) => Name = name;

  public override bool Equals(object? obj)
  {
      if (obj is Person person) return Name == person.Name;
      return false;
  }
  public override int GetHashCode() => Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: А в книге по C# этот момент не объясняется?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563090/220553 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/198520/220553

Comment: Ну, что-то будет работать. Но как только вы захотите использовать ваши объекты в словаре в качестве ключей или в хэшсете, тут то всё это и понадобится. Ну и если вы объекты просто где-то захотите сравнивать, то `Equals` само по себе понадобится.

Comment: Автор, а вы представьте себя на месте метода Union. Вот вам дали на вход два набора объектов, и вам надо выдать на выход один набор без повторов. Как вы будете решать эту задачу без возможности сравнить объекты?

Answer (score 0):

**Equals** переопределяется, чтобы сравнивать объекты. К примеру, у тебя 2 объекта одного типа, и они могут быть равны или одинаковы по каким-то условиям, общая сумма всех внутренних переменных одинакова или полностью идентичны, но быть независимыми друг от друга. Для этого и существует метод Equals, который для других пользователей твоего куска кода, позволяет сравнивать объекты.
Можно так-же этому методы дать перегрузки, чтоб он принимал не только "object? obj", но и "int" и прочие типы объектов, но там уже переопределений не будет.

**GetHashCode** используется для ускорения сравнения двух объектов. То есть если требуется узнать, одинаковы ли какие-то два объекта, то сначала сравниваются их хэш-коды. Если они различаются, то значит и объекты различны. Если же совпадают, то тогда начинается дорогостоящее "настоящее" сравнение через Equals.
Таким образом, GetHashCode, во-первых, должен совпадать для одинаковых объектов, во-вторых, по-возможности отличаться для разных объектов и в-третьих, достаточно быстро вычисляться (чтобы в его использовании вообще был смысл).
В вашем случае вряд ли преобразование целых в строку и затем их сравнение будет выполняться быстрее чем сравнение чисел напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

В том-то и дело, что может не объясняться. Часто базовые вещи опускают.
Для "GetHashCode()" в документации https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0 написано: "A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in collections that are based on a hash table". Это значит, что если использовать класс **в качестве ключа** коллекции не планируется, то можно и не переопределять. В качестве ключа чаще всего используются какие-то базовые типы вроде int или string, для которых вычисление хеша уже реализовано. "Equals()" используется в паре с "GetHashCode()".

То же самое для "==". Метод позволяет сравнивать объекты с помощью операции равенства. Если такие сравнения не планируются, то можно не переопределять. (Сделал уточнение согласно комментарию.)

Интересно, что переопределение "==" требует переопределения "Equals()", но не наоборот.

Остальное надо читать самому в https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

Comment: `==` не будет работать, если вы просто переопределите эти методы. Для их работы нужно переопределять сами операторы дополнительно.