# Что будет если hashcode объекта в HashMap поменяется?

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashcode

Я знаю, что если поменять любое поле объекта, которое является ключом в `HashMap`, то `hashcode` этого объекта поменяется. Вопрос, можно ли как то получить доступ к потерянному объекту в `hashmap` (`getValue()`)? Если ссылки(ключи) не указывают на этот объект удалит ли его сборщик мусора из кучи?

Comment: мне кажется, вы не очень понимаете, как работает hashmap. Хешкод там нужен для того, чтобы найти ключ. Если вы добавляете ключ в мапу, а потом меняете состояние ключа, то вы просто не найдете этот клоюч поиском в мапе. Но вы всё еще можете пройтись по всем ключам в мапе и найти там свой.

Comment: Просто это был вопрос на одном из собеседований, я понимаю что менять состояние ключа такая себе идея, но не знал можно ли найти потеряный ключ, спасибо)

Comment: не совсем в тему, но вчера только отвечал на вопрос про хешкод. в джаве дела плюс-минус также обстоят https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1520657/179763

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Найти можно. Для этого надо проитерировать все бакеты и найти в ключе именно тот объект:

   ```
    Map<MyObject, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.value = 42;
    map.put(myObject, 1);
    System.out.println(map.get(myObject)); // 1
    myObject.value = 422;
    System.out.println(map.get(myObject)); // null

    for (Map.Entry<MyObject, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() == myObject) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue()); // 1
        }
    }


   class MyObject {
     Integer value;

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ...
     }

     @Override


     public int hashCode() {
          return value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0;
     } 
   }
   ```

   2. GC вхождение не удалит. Если надо чтобы удаляло, вернее чтобы сделать ненулевой вероятность удаления, то используется `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: Спасибо, это ответ на мой вопрос!) Но, кое что остается не понятным мне - как Entry сопоставляет ключ/значение если ключ указывает на null?

Comment: @Venoman9867 вроде, если я верно помню, ключ не может быть null в хештабице

Comment: @Venoman9867 Ключ не указывает на null, после изменения хеша ключа по нему не удается найти значение, однако ключ из хеш таблицы никуда не делся и поэтому его можно отыскать путем сравнения ссылок, имея ссылку на исходный объект ключа.

Comment: @tym32167, есть реализации, допускающие `null` в качестве ключей, в частности та же [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) или `LinkedHashMap`.  Для устаревшего `Hashtable` будет выброшено NPE.